# Need some sample data fetching code for Dashing app on Heroku + Salesforce.com

Tags: postgresql, heroku, salesforce, dashing

My goal is to create a Dashing app hosted on heroku that will display support case information from salesforce.com using heroku connect.

I'm just looking for some sample dashing widget code that would show me how to get the data out of the heroku postgres db.  I've read the info on the dashing wiki (http://dashing.io/#widgets) but I need more help with how this works in relation to heroku connect to salesforce.com.  As an example, I'd like to get a list of open support cases by product.

thanks in advanced,
Keith

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Heroku Connect check out the Trailhead Quick Start: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/quickstart-heroku-connect

If you want to use Java and the Salesforce REST APIs, check out:
https://www.jamesward.com/2016/01/26/quick-force-java-getting-started-with-salesforce-rest-in-java